# vue 3 transition animation on leave doesnt work

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, vue-transitions

im trying to animate my modal window with fade and with some slide.
Fade works correctly but slide is not, cause there is not workin animation on disappear, only apperance. And slide work only with "appear" tag. Does anyone had any idea about this?

[image: template]
[image: style]

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) when asking a question?